# Can the quota on QnAMaker Preview subscription be raised or removed?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

We recently started receiving 403 Quota Exceeded error responses from the QnAMaker Preview API when calling the get answer endpoint. I suppose this is because the monthly quota of getting answers has been exceeded.

My question is if there is a way to upgrade the QnAMaker Preview subscription so that quota would at least be higher and we could continue using the service? And to do it so that we could still be using the Preview version and would not be required to migrate to the GA version.

The reason why we are hesitant to migrate to GA is that it does not have the Train API the preview version has. Train API is very important to our business goals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are right now not increasing quota for the preview stack, as we want the users to move to GA stack.

We are working on enabling the Train API. Can you drop a mail to qnamakersupport@microsoft.com describing your scenario and how you are using the Train API. We might be able to suggest some workarounds.

Comment: Thank your for your answer! Are you absolutely sure that there is no way to increase the quota? We were asking for a bigger quota already before QnAMaker was GA but I'm not sure if we ever got it. Is there a way for me to check what our subscription is and what the quota is?

Comment: Regarding migration to GA it would be a significant amount of work for us and we decided to not do it before GA would have the Train API. I can email you the details of our scenario so maybe you can understand our situation better.

Comment: It turns out our subscription has already been upgraded to premium tier so that we have a higher quota. The tier was just not activated yet, since we had not reset the subscription keys. Once we did that, we managed to get the service working again! Thanks for your help!